# Project Matching Query Does Not Exist Error?

Tags: django, django-views

This is the view:

```
def showProject(request, project_slug):
project = Project.objects.get(slug=project_slug)
tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(project=project)
payload = { 'project':project, 'tickets':tickets }
return render(request, 'project/project.html', payload)
```

This is the error:

Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\project\views.py" in showProject
  13.   project = Project.objects.get(slug=project_slug)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\manager.py" in get
  132.         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  349.                     % self.model._meta.object_name)

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /project/ticket/
Exception Value: Project matching query does not exist.

A more detailed explanation of what is expected: I have a sidebar that lists all open "tickets." When I click on one of those tickets, it should open it. Instead when I try to open it, I am getting this error. What is happening?

Per, request, here is the model class:

```
class Project(models.Model):
"""simple project for tracking purposes"""
name = models.CharField(max_length = 64)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 100, unique=True,blank=True, null=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="+")
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = 1)
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
parent = models.ForeignKey("self", related_name="children", null=True, blank=True)
repository = models.ForeignKey("Repository", related_name="projects", null=True, blank=True)
book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name="+", null=True, blank=True)
acl = models.ManyToManyField(AclEntry)
def save (self):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = '-'.join(self.name.lower().split())
    if not self.book:
        book = Book(name=self.name, owner=self.owner)
        book.save()
        self.book = book
    super(Project, self).save()
```

It seems that everything I try to do is going back to this, and I don't understand why? What am I missing? Thanks so much!

Comment: Another note, I also have a "deleteTicket" function, which when I try it, gets the same response.

Comment: Please show us your model class.

Answer (score 2):

```
project = Project.objects.get(slug=project_slug)
```

is raising an exception (DoesNotExist), meaning that there is no project in the Project table with a slug corresponding to the value in **project_slug**

The regex in your urls might be wrong, the link sending you to showProject view might be wrong or there mightn't be a project in the table yet corresponding to that slug

Comment: I understand what it means- but I don't understand why I'm getting it... This was working fine yesterday, I worked on the "tickets" piece, had to change it to "filter" so it would be iterable and worked on some other views. I have not touched the template code (it is a base.html file that is gets extended). When I create a new project, with a new corresponding ticket, clicking on it returns the same error- even though I know the data is there.

Comment: I've mentioned 3 possible problems above