# Matching query does not exist?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

This is the view:

```
def showProject(request, project_slug):
project = Project.objects.get(slug=project_slug)
tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(project=project)
payload = { 'project':project, 'tickets':tickets }
return render(request, 'project/project.html', payload)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\\project\views.py" in showProject
  13.   project = Project.objects.get(slug=project_slug)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\manager.py" in get
  132.         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  349.                     % self.model._meta.object_name)

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /project/ticket/

Exception Value: Project matching query does not exist.
```

A more detailed explanation of what is expected: I have a sidebar that lists all open "tickets." When I click on one of those tickets, it should open it. Instead when I try to open it, I'm getting this error. What is happening? 
Here is the model class:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    """simple project for tracking purposes"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 64)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 100, unique=True,blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="+")
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = 1)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", related_name="children", null=True, blank=True)
    repository = models.ForeignKey("Repository", related_name="projects", null=True, blank=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name="+", null=True, blank=True)
    acl = models.ManyToManyField(AclEntry)
    def save (self):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = '-'.join(self.name.lower().split())
        if not self.book:
            book = Book(name=self.name, owner=self.owner)
            book.save()
            self.book = book
        super(Project, self).save()
```

Here is the template code:

```
{% block title %}Tickets: {{project.name}}{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<div id="project-nav">
<span><a href="/project/{{project.slug}}/">Tickets</a></span>
<span><a href="/book/{{book.slug}}{{book.name}}">Docs</a></span>
<span><a href="/project/{{project.slug}}/browse">Browser</a></span>
</div>
<div id="action-nav">
{% block actions %}
<span><a href="/project/{{project.slug}}/tickets/create">Create Ticket</a></span>
<span><a href="/project/{{ project.slug }}/tickets/recent">Recent           Activity</a>      </span>
<span><a href="/project/{{ project.slug }}/tickets/my/">My Tickets</a></span>
{% endblock %}
</div>
{% for ticket in tickets %}

<div class="ticket">
<div class="ticket-header">
    <div class="ticket-title">
        <a href="/project/ticket/{{ticket.pk}}">{{ticket.subject}}</a>
    </div>
    <div id="ticket-number">
        #{{ticket.pk}}
    </div>
    <div id="ticket-state">
        {{ticket.get_state_display}}
    </div>
    <div id="ticket-info">
        Reported by {{ticket.created_by}} | created: {{ticket.created_on   }} | modified: {{ticket.modified_on}}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

It seems that everything I try to do is going back to this, and I don't understand why. What am I missing? Thanks so much!

Comment: Please post the (template?) code you're using to generate the ticket links.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Project Matching Query Does Not Exist Error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524981/project-matching-query-does-not-exist-error)

Comment: Another alternative is to use `Project.objects.filter` instead of `get`, which wouldn't throw an error, but can give you more then one result.

Answer (score 16):

It says there is no `Project` object whose `slug` is equal to `project_slug`.

You should catch the exception as below

```
try:
    Project.objects.get(slug=project_slug)
except Project.DoesNotExist:
    raise sth...
```

Comment: The more interesting thing is how he's getting a generated list of links involving a project that doesn't exist.