# django matching query does not exist using pk form foreignkey

Tags: django, save, foreign-keys

I'm trying to generate a def to save an entry in the database with the following code in the models.py

```
from alumno.models import alumno
from curso.models import cursos

class matricula(models.Model):
    curso = models.ForeignKey(cursos)
    alumno = models.ForeignKey(alumno)
    fecha_matricula = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    codigo_inscripcion = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=True, editable=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.codigo_inscripcion,)

    def crear_codigo(self):
        idAlumno = '%05d' % matricula.objects.get(pk=self.id).alumno.id
        idCurso = '%04d' % matricula.objects.get(pk=self.id).curso.id
        anio = self.fecha_matricula.year
        return u'%s-%s-%s' % (idAlumno, idCurso, anio)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.codigo_inscripcion:
            self.codigo_inscripcion = self.crear_codigo()
    return super(matricula, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But I keep getting an error like this:

```
Exception Type:     DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    matricula matching query does not exist.
```

according've been reading other [responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524981/project-matching-query-does-not-exist-error) the problem would be the url.py but not encuentor no reference in the DBUG .

in the debug is reference to the first this line

```
        idAlumno = '%05d' % matricula.objects.get(pk=self.id).alumno.id
```

what I do not understand is that in the shell and returns the value I need 'm not sure what could be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `save()` method is called for the new object the `id` property of this object is `None`.  Of course object with `pk=None` does not exist.

Why you load the current record from DB.  Use the object's fields directly:

```
def crear_codigo(self):
    return u'%05d-%04d-%s' % (self.alumno.id, self.curso.id,
                              self.fecha_matricula.year)
```